# Is there any way to create collage from some images and then set as wallpaper in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, wallpaper, flutter-image

I am not interested how to set a wallpaper, because there are a lot of examples and documentation. Also for saving the wallpaper to the mobile gallery, or taking the photo paths from the gallery.
I've already read about this.
I am not finding a way to create different layouts (collages) to merge some images into a single image. I found the *Image Collage Widget*, but there is no documentation at all, and I don't know how to put manually the images instead of choosing from the gallery, to save the resulted collage etc.

```
ImageCollageWidget(
   collageType: CollageType.LeftBig,
   withImage: false,
   filePath: '',
),
```

Any other solutions? The user can add up to 12 images, and the wallpaper needs to be created as a collage depending on how many images are added by the user. This functionality is already implemented.
I thought about using *Staggered Grid View*, but it would be a lot of variants depending of number of images. So I should check how many images are and depending of it, create 11 different implementations.
Do you have any other idea? I am new to flutter.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no readymade solution for this but you can use staggered_grid_view to create collage & make custom collage layouts based on number of images selected for the collage. This is already covered in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYXAaTAxbLw).

Also in this tutorial, it is shown how to put the images manually instead of choosing from the gallery & to save the resulted collage on local file storage.